# Is this behaviour correct when using the Wikipedia search box?

Tags: wikipedia

I am searching using two key words "**statue**" and "**liberté**" on the French Wikipédia page:

[image]

*None of the first 3 results are even remotely close to the article I am looking for* (why are these results even in the list of results?).

And the article I am looking for, while very close to the terms I entered, is near the bottom of the page in **eighth** position.

For reference, the title of the article I am looking for is:

[image]

I know that if I type the exact name of the article I'm looking for, I'll find it on top of the search results. Or if I google "wikipedia statue liberté".

But why is this result so far down when I type only the two main words of the article's page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search has since improved:

[image: same search in 2022]